# Different microphones for machine learning dataset

Tags: audio, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm currently following along with the Tensorflow simple audio recognition tutorial found
[here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/audio_recognition)  and wanted to know if having audio recorded by different microphones in my dataset will negatively affect the outcome of my training. Should all audio be recorded by the same type of microphone?

Answer (score -1):

That depends on how you will use the trained model in the future. If you expect this model to work well with different types of microphones, and assuming different microphones affect the actual audio recorded, then you would want to record with a variety of microphones.

Or, alternatively, you might characterize the differences produced by different microphones and modify your dataset such that the samples contain the variances you found between microphones. This is called data augmentation and is a very common and recommended practice, however this might not necessarily be an easy task. Data augmentation is generally specific to the dataset and type of data you're using, so this might only be one example of data augmentation you would want to employ. Another typical example with audio is to add in varying types of background noise to produce a much larger unique dataset in which it has to pick out the desired signal.

On the other hand, you are going to use your model only on a specific microphone, then it makes sense to train it with only that microphone, since you don't care how well or poorly it might perform using a different microphone.

If this is just an exercise in learning, then I wouldn't worry about this detail at all. In fact, it doesn't seem likely to me that different microphones will produce a significantly different audio profile. But hey, I could very well be wrong.

I like to think about questions like this from a distinctly human perspective. Ask yourself this: If I were to hire a data entry person to perform this task and I was going to give them a few examples to teach them how to perform the task, would it benefit them if those samples came from multiple microphones? If the answer is yes, then treat a learning algorithm the same as you would the human and give them the same variety.

Comment: So if i was going to run this on an IoT device I should be using the same microphone to obtain the dataset that i would have on the device. As of right now I have been collecting audio data from youtube videos but in an application where I know the hardware I should just grab it from that type of hardware?

Comment: In general, yes, however, I wouldn't prioritize this very highly as it seems unlikely to make a major impact on your results.